# Unable to start nodes after upgrading from Cassandra 3.11.13 to 4.0.5

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 nodes cluster with version 3.11.13 built on Ubuntu 22.04 on EC2 and tried to upgrade to 4.0.5. I used apt install with openjdk-8-jdk for 3.11.13 and built the cluster with simplesnitch since all 3 nodes are in the same VPC subnet.

Based on the document I installed 4.0.5 with openjdk-11-jdk on the same nodes and ran the upgradesstables successfully. But after that I was not able to bring those 3 nodes into the cluster. I checked nodetool status and nodetool gossipinfo and all are not working. please advise how can I fix it or what steps I need to follow.

Comment: t2.small with 1 vCPU and 2GB RAM is not a recommended hardware on both 3.11.13 as well as 4.0.latest. See [here for hardware choices](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/operating/hardware.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without information on what the problem is, it's impossible for us to give meaningful advice.

You will need to review the Cassandra logs for clues. In particular, focus on the error(s) which indicates why the startup failed. The full error message and the full stack trace is what you're looking for to determine why it failed and what to do next. Cheers!